# jQuery selector not behaving as expected inside a click function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, scope

I have a number of div's  (containing ace editors) on a page. The editor itself should only appear upon request so I've added an anchor above each div with a click function to expose it.

The issue is that instead of just the div I want to display appearing, all such hidden divs are unhiding?  Can anyone spot the mistake?

#### HTML

```
<p>Description of block one:</p>
<a class="expand-textarea" style="display: none" href="#">Click to Edit</a>
<div id="pref_id1_cont" style="position:relative; height:250px; width: 100%;">
    <p>Ace Editor 1 goes here!</p>
</div>

<p>Description of block 2: </p> 
<a class="expand-textarea" style="display: none" href="#">Click to Edit</a>
<div id="pref_id2_cont" style="position:relative; height:250px; width: 100%;">
    <p>Ace Editor 2 goes here!</p>
</div>
```

#### JS

```
window.onload = function() {
    $('# pref_id1_cont').hide();
    $('.expand-textarea').show().click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
        $('#pref_id1_cont').show();
    });

    $('#pref_id2_cont').hide();
    $('.expand-textarea').show().click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
        $('#pref_id2_cont').show();
    });
};
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KTDyr/7/)

Any suggestions on how to do this in a simpler manner would also be much appreciated. Currently this is some old code i'm updating which relies on lots of templates.  In the long run, i'm looking to just create the editor blocks dynamically rather than duplicate js for each block.  The above approach is just for sanity checking what I've already got.

Answer (score 2):

Try this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/KTDyr/10/)

```
window.onload = function() {
    $('[id^=pref_id]').hide();
    $('.expand-textarea').show().click(function() {
        $(this).hide().next('div').show();
    });
};​
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the same class on all the `a` tags, so when one is clicked each of those event handlers are firing. Try something like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    $('#pref_id1_cont').hide();
    $('#pref_id2_cont').hide();
    $('#pref_id3_cont').hide();

    $('.expand-textarea').click(function() {
        $(this).next("div").show();
    });
};​
```

By using [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/), you can get the next `div` after the `.expand-textarea`. In this case it's the `pref_id#_cont` element.

> Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of
>   matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next
>   sibling only if it matches that selector.

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KTDyr/11/)**

Answer (score 0):

I would approach the problem something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/KTDyr/14/

HTML

```
<div class="con">
    <p class="expand-textarea-con">        
        Show the following HTML in the OPAC, 
        <a class="expand-textarea" href="#">Click to Edit</a>
    </p>
    <div class="expanded-textarea" style="display:none">
        <p>Ace Editor 1 goes here!</p>
        <p class="expanded-textarea-close">Close</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".expand-textarea").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.expanded-textarea').show();
    $(this).parent().hide();

});    

$(".expanded-textarea-close").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().hide();
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.expand-textarea-con').show();

});
```

CSS

```
.expand-textarea {
display:inline;
color:blue;
text-decoration:underline;
cursor:pointer;
}

.expanded-textarea {
width: 100%; 
height:250px;    
position:relative;
background:orange;    
}

.expanded-textarea-close {
color:blue;
text-decoration:underline;
cursor:pointer;
}​
```